# Systemd service prefix on ExecStart=@/path/to/executable doesn't change the `argv[0]`

Tags: systemd, filenames, arguments

According to the manual `man systemd.service` using the prefix `@` says this:

> If the executable path is prefixed with "@", the second specified
> token will be passed as "argv[0]" to the executed process (instead of
> the actual filename), followed by the further arguments specified.

But when I run the service with a bash script or python script the filename or argv[0] has no effect. This only works when I use a program written in c language.

Inside my service I have:

```
[Unit]
Description=After service Number: 1

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=@/home/edgar/bin/script "after-1-service" "1" "Args from after-service"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run this service using a **c** program the filename takes the value of **"after-1-service"** and the other arguments ("1","Args from after-service") are passed correctly as **argv[1]** and **argv[2]** respectively.

But when I run the service using a **python** or **bash** script the value of **"after-1-service"** has no effect and prints the main filename of the script and the arguments "1" and "Args from after-service" are passed correctly as **argv[1]** and **argv[2]** respectively.

In the case of python and bash script what is happening to the **"after-1-service"** argument? because if the filename or argv[0] is ignored I guess it should be passed the **"after-1-service"** as argv[1] and the other arguments should be paased as **argv[2]** and **argv[3]**

This is my code written in `c` for printing the filename:

```
printf("Filename: %s\n",argv[0]);
```

This is my code written in `python`:

```
print(f"Filename:  {sys.argv[0]}")
```

And this is my code written in `bash`:

```
echo Filename $0
```

I've tested those scripts using symbolic links and filename changes correctly, so I guess this only works for c programs or maybe it's a bug of systemd (version 251).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the `argv[0]` of the shell process is not the same as the `$0` within the shell script. This can be seen even when starting a script normally:

```
$ cat argv0.sh 
#!/bin/sh
echo "Filename $0"
$ sh ./argv0.sh 
Filename ./argv0.sh
```

The shell calls something like `execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "./argv0.sh"], [env vars...])`, i.e. `argv[0]` gets set to `sh`. However, within the script `$0` is the name of *script* that runs, the man page says:

> `0`
> Expands to the name of the shell or shell script.  This is set at shell initialization.  If bash is invoked with a file of commands, `$0` is set to the name of that file."

As far as that functionality is concerned  doesn't matter what the name of the *interpreter* is set to.

I assume the issue is similar in principle with Python, and e.g. the manual says:

> `sys.argv`
> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. `argv[0]` is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not).

However, Python 3.10 also has `sys.orig_argv` which looks like it might be what you're looking for:

> `sys.orig_argv`
> The list of the original command line arguments passed to the Python executable.

---

If the shell is started with `sh -c "code..." arg0 arg1 ...` , then the first argument after the code is assigned to `$0`, so you could use that and run something like this:

```
$ sh -c '. ./argv0.sh' foobar
Filename foobar
```

With `. ./argv0.sh` used to run the script in the same shell, so that it sees the same `$0` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I didn't know about that.
I had to use without the prefix '@' because it had problems.
So I used the `sh -c ...` code and it worked for bash.
In the case of python it seems it doesn't work, what prints is "/bin/python3" as argv[0] and the filename as argv[1].

Comment: And why does `. ./argv0.sh` work and not `./argv0.sh`? I understand that `. ./argv0.sh` is the same as `source ./argv0.sh` and both run the script (with the some different behavior), but why with `source` the script takes the arguments and with `./argv0.sh` not?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, because if you run `./argv0.sh` the shell starts a new shell instance to run the script, first initializing its `$0` according to the normal rules, so using the name of the script file. That wouldn't help in making the script see the manually-set `$0`. With `. scriptfile`, no new shell is started, but it's (almost) the same as if we ran `sh -c 'echo "Filename $0"' foobar` directly.

Comment: Thank you again! Those are really good examples :).