# Why isn't `exec -a` working the way I expect?

Tags: bash

I'm reading up on `exec` and how to use the `-a` flag.  The [SS64 docs](https://ss64.com/bash/exec.html) seem accurate; they say the following:

> exec:
>
> Execute a command
>
> Syntax:
>
> ```
> exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
> ```
>
> Options:
>
> ```
> -c   Causes command to be executed with an empty environment.
>
> -l   Place a dash at the beginning of the zeroth arg passed to command.
>      (This is what the login program does.)
>
> -a   The shell passes name as the zeroth argument to command.
> ```

To test this out, I wrote two scripts, one named `foo/baz` and one named `foo/buzz`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# foo/baz

exec -a blah ./foo/bar 1 2
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# foo/buzz

exec ./foo/bar 1 2
```

Each of these scripts runs the same child script, `foo/bar`, which does the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Hello world"
echo "0: $0"
echo "1: $1"
echo "2: $2"
```

My goal is to see what effect `-a` has on the 0th and subsequent arguments.  If `-a` causes the 0th argument to change to the argument you pass to the `-a` flag, then I would expect the 0th argument when I run `foo/baz` to be `blah`, since that's what I pass to `-a`.  However, when I run the scripts, the output is the same in both cases:

```
~/Workspace/OpenSource (master)  $ ./foo/baz 
Hello world
0: /Users/richiethomas/Workspace/OpenSource/foo/bar
1: 1
2: 2
~/Workspace/OpenSource (master)  $ ./foo/buzz
Hello world
0: /Users/richiethomas/Workspace/OpenSource/foo/bar
1: 1
2: 2
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Or is my expectation incorrect somehow?

Also, a related question- what is the use case of overriding the 0th argument, as opposed to just accessing any passed-in args via $1, $2, $3, etc.?

Comment: Perhaps, adding the arguments **1 2** manually overrides the 0th argument option.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the case.  When I remove them and re-run the scripts, the 0th argument is still that full filepath, but args 1 and 2 are each blank.

Comment: Please try `exec -a SomeName sh -c 'echo $0'`.

Comment: @QuartzCristal your command does result in the output I expected.

Comment: See also [Systemd service prefix on ExecStart=@/path/to/executable doesn't change the `argv[0]`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/714391/170373)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> what is the use case of overriding the 0th argument...?

Some programs change their behavior based on how they are called. For example, [`busybox`](https://busybox.net/) is a multi-call binary that behaves this way. Using `exec -a` we get different behavior depending on the value of the zeroth argument:

```
$ bash -c 'exec -a date /usr/sbin/busybox'
Sat Sep 17 20:22:14 EDT 2022
$ bash -c 'exec -a uptime /usr/sbin/busybox'
 20:22:17 up 23:48,  load average: 0.10, 0.20, 0.15
```

This also demonstrates that `exec -a <something>` behaves as documented.

> Am I doing something wrong? Or is my expectation incorrect somehow?

The problem here is that you're working with shell scripts. When you enter `./foo/baz` on the command line, you're not actually running a command named `./foo/baz`: you're running something like `/bin/bash /path/to/foo/baz`. While `exec -a` effects the zeroth argument passed to the shell...the shell doesn't care, and it uses its own logic when setting up the variables visible to the shell script, including `$0` (which contains the *script* name), and the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`... (which contain the arguments to the script).

(This isn't specific to shell scripts -- the same would hold true of pretty any interpreted code.)

Comment: It should also be noted that, while some interpreters will try to preserve the value of the 0th argument, `/usr/bin/env` typically won't, so bash isn't even at fault here.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're calling an interpreted script rather than a native binary. Compile this C program, putting the result at `./foo/bar` where your script used to be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    puts("Hello world");
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
}
```

Once you do that, you'll see the behavior you were expecting. The reason for the discrepancy is that when calling interpreted scripts, `argv[0]` gets hijacked to tell the interpreter the name of the script. Usually this goes unnoticed, since in most cases, that's what it was anyway. You only noticed it because you went out of your way to make it different.

Comment: you also get `$0` different from the original `argv[0]` with something like `sh somescript.sh foo bar`.

Answer (score 2):

The key point is that `exec` will set the `$0` only for the command on that command line.

Try, for example:

```
$ bash

$ exec -a SomeName sh -c 'echo "The name is: $0"'
The name is: SomeName
```

It just so happens that the shell closes because the exec replaces it and when that ends, the shell process also ends. That is why you need to ask for a new shell using the `bash` command. If not, the shell will close and will also close the terminal with it.

If you want to follow what the exec command does, try something like:

```
$ strace -fe execve bash -c 'exec -a SomeName echo test' one two
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "exec -a SomeName echo test", "one", "two"], 0x7ffdca326e60 /* 77 vars */) = 0
execve("/usr/bin/echo", ["SomeName", "test"], 0x55d4dcf02c50 /* 76 vars */) = 0
test
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

And that is useful to make some executable changes as its calling name changes:

```
$ ( exec -a date -- busybox -ud '12:34' +'%F %T %Z' )
2022-09-18 12:34:00 UTC

$ ( exec -a ls busybox )
fileone
filetwo
```