# Soft link will pass filename as 1st parameter to target?

Tags: symlink, io, utilities

https://github.com/adurbin/iotools

Original usage is:

```
./iotools rdmsr x xxxxx
```

when I doing:

```
ln -sf iotools rdmsr
```

then I can do:

```
rdmsr x xxxxx
```

Why??

because when doing soft linking, it will pass the filename as 1st parameter ?

Comment: That's working successfully and as Stephen Kitt said that's related to `argv[0]`.  A good example is about `/bin/sh` which usually is a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`.  If you run `sh` you will notice that this behaves differently to  `bash` and the reason is just about how the shell was invoked (this is determined by `argv[0]`). You can check  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717870/why-does-bin-sh-behave-differently-to-bin-bash-even-if-one-points-to-the-other) about this behavior.

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/714394/414186) might be useful for a better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention, the list of arguments for any command includes the command itself. When you run

```
./iotools rdmsr x xxxxx
```

`iotools` is run with arguments `./iotools`, `rdmsr`, `x`, and `xxxxx`. When you run

```
rdmsr x xxxxx
```

`iotools` is run with arguments `rdmsr`, `x`, and `xxxxx`.

Most commands look at arguments starting with the second (number 1 since numbering starts at 0). But some, [including `iotools`](https://github.com/adurbin/iotools/blob/master/commands.c#L112), take the first argument into account if necessary. In `iotools` case, it first checks whether its second argument (`argv[1]`) is a command, and if so, uses that; otherwise, it checks whether its first argument (`argv[0]`) is a command.